# How can I get a help message for zsh builtins?

Tags: command-line, zsh, documentation, shell-builtin

If I want to get a brief usage message for a bash builtin, I can use `help <builtin>` at a command prompt, e.g.

```
$ help export
export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    Set export attribute for shell variables.

    Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.

    Options:
      -f        refer to shell functions
      -n        remove the export property from each NAME
      -p        display a list of all exported variables and functions

    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

How can I do this in zsh?  I've tried

```
% export --help
zsh: bad option: -e
```

and

```
% help export
zsh: command not found: help
```

Also the word "help" isn't anywhere in `man zshbuiltins`.

Answer (score 9):

thanks to @don_crissti linking through this [Arch wiki documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Help_command).
For some reason the code on the Arch wiki causes this error on invocation

> /home/velour/.zshrc:unalias:368: no such hash table element: run-help

<sub>zsh --version => zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)</sub>

so to get it to work, I added the below block to `~/.zshrc`, then commented out the alias commands.

```
autoload -Uz run-help
autoload -Uz run-help-git
autoload -Uz run-help-svn
autoload -Uz run-help-svk
#unalias run-help
#alias help=run-help
```

and simply invoke with

```
run-help <builtin>
```

So now I get

```
% run-help export

export [ name[=value] ... ]
       The specified names are marked for automatic export to the envi-
       ronment  of subsequently executed commands.  Equivalent to type-
       set -gx.  If a parameter specified does not already exist, it is
       created in the global scope.
```

Comment: @don_crissti I have updated my answer with details of error and zsh version.

Comment: Maybe it's [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsh/+bug/305346)

Comment: I tried this without uncommenting out the aliases, and I just get the zshbuiltins manual page. How can I get help for a specific builtin without searching for it in there?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `run-help` function above is the [`zman`](https://github.com/zdharma/zinit-configs/blob/master/psprint/functions/zman) mentioned in [a Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/g1srzn/why_is_it_so_hard_to_get_documentation_for_the/fnkc9ff/). It’s part of Zinit, but seems to work independently.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to `.zshrc` worked for me.
(building upon the answer of the_velour_fog)

```
unalias run-help
alias help=run-help
autoload -Uz run-help
```

Before `run-help` was an alias for `man`.

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)
$ zsh
\$ type run-help
run-help is an alias for man
\$ unalias run-help
\$ type run-help
run-help not found
\$ autoload -Uz run-help
\$ type run-help
run-help is an autoload shell function
\$ alias help=run-help
\$ help export
export [ name[=value] ... ]
       The specified names are marked for automatic export to the envi-
       ronment  of subsequently executed commands.  Equivalent to type-
       set -gx.  If a parameter specified does not already exist, it is
       created in the global scope.
```

Answer (score 0):

They have an own man page:

```
man zshbuiltins
```

Comment: And the question says, "*the word "help" isn't anywhere in `man zshbuiltins`*."  So this answer adds no value.

Comment: All the information that `help` would ever provide is found on the man page of `zshbuiltins`. If you want to know the options of `export`, you use `help export` in bash but in zsh you use `man zshbuiltins` and there you get the options for `export`. After all you also use `man ls` and not `help ls`; zsh just treats built-ins like non-builtins as the POSIX standard does not require anything to be built-in. And `export` is found on the man page, help not as zsh simply doesn't know any command named help and POSIX does not require that to exist at all.