# How to resolve this error for 'help' command not found in Kali Linux?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, shell-builtin

I know that `help` is a shell built-in internal command used to find about built in commands such as `cd`. But it is not working in my Kali Linux terminal in VirtualBox. It is showing the following error:

```
Command 'help' not found, did you mean:
  command 'dhelp' from deb dhelp
  command 'yelp' from deb yelp
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a help message for zsh builtin's?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282645/how-can-i-get-a-help-message-for-zsh-builtins)

Answer (score 8):

`help` is a builtin command in `bash`, not all shells. You seem to be using something that isn't bash. Most likely `zsh` since [that is the default shell](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/linux/kali-linux-20204-switches-the-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh/) in recent versions of Kali. If you want to use `bash`, either run it manually with `bash` or use `chsh` to set it as the default for your account:

```
chsh rs90
```

And then follow the prompts and give it `/bin/bash`. If your username isn't `rs90`, use whatever your user name is.

A final note: Kali is not a regular operating system. It is a highly specialized tool for professionals. If you are new to Linux, as your question suggests, Kali is a ***very bad choice*** to learn the system. Although it has been popularized by some movies and TV shows, there's nothing a "hacker" can do on Kali than cannot be done with regular Linux flavors, you just need to install some Kali packages. I would urge you to start with a regular distribution and not use Kali since using Kali will just make your life harder. Also see: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/22222)

Comment: It is still not working I changed to /bin/bash then also it is showing same error

Comment: Firstly, when you try something and it fails, you should update your question with "following (this guy)'s advise I (explain here what steps exactly you took). The result was (explain exactly what the result is). This so that community members don't have to go through extended commentaries to know the details of your situation. I'm seconding @terdon's advise - read what's in the link. Before you tackle Kali you really should be able to figure out what went wrong... I'll give you a hint: /bin/bash.

Comment: @RS90 after changing it, you need to open a new terminal for the change to take effect. Or just run `bash` manually.